# How to optimise Text to HTML ratio for SEO by separating the HTML into multiple files?

Tags: css, javascript, seo

I have run into an issue with my Wordpress/Elementor site and I hope you guys have any advice.

I did an site audit with Semrush, and as it turns out the ratio of text to HTML is only 1-2% but it should be at least 10% for SEO optimisation.

My site already has relatively little text because it is just a way to redirect users to my services. I looked into the source code and I noticed a lot of my plugins were adding unnecessary html classes and scripts. After disabling most of these plugins and clearing the cache, the ratio is still way too low.

I think the main issue now is that Elementor adds a lot of html classes to every element which is why the ratio is off. Since my pages are built with Elementor, I cant get rid of those.

Are there any tools or plugins available that clean up the HTML code of Wordpress/Elementor sites? Maybe by separating the HTML into multiple files (especially the  elements)? I honestly don't know what to do, so I'd truly appreciate your input.

The website: https://nurenoveren.nl/

Edit: I already enabled the settings from the Automtimise plugin with no success.

Comment: Separating HTML into multiple files wouldn't do anything. It's all delivered as a single page anyway. Any tool for resolving this issue would be specific to Elementor. Since third party plugins are off topic here, so you'd need to ask about that in an Elementor community. I'd argue that WordPress itself doesn't have this problem, but even if it did any solution wouldn't be relevant to you because you're using Elementor and that's where all the HTML is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Elementor does add a lot of extra html markup. Not much you can do other than recreate the html without elementor. If you use elementor and create a section, then put html in an html widget you can bypass all the extra stuff. You can also create a shortcode to bypass the elementor editor then have your html in a file and include that in your shortcode.
Also, don't nest the containers too much in elementor, that can add a lot of html markup.